# If the moving average of a process is a martingale, is the process a martingale?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, martingales

**Problem set up:**

Let $\mathcal F_t$ be a filtration satisfying the usual conditions. Let $T > 0$ be a fixed real number, and define the filtration $\mathcal H_t := \mathcal F_{T + t}$.

Suppose a cadlag adapted process $X$  is almost surely locally integrable, i.e. for any compact set $C \subset \mathbb R_+$we have $\int_C X_t \ dt < \infty$ a.s.

Define the moving average process $M$ by $M_t := \int_{[t, t + T]} X_s ds$.

Suppose that the following conditions hold:

- Almost surely, $X_0 = X_s$ for all $s \leq T$.
- $M_t$ is a $\mathcal H_t$-martingale.

> **Question:** Is it true that $X$ is an $\mathcal F_t$-martingale?

Comment: While I do not know the answer, note that if $X_t$ is an $\mathcal F_t$-martingale, then typically $M_t$ is *not* an $\mathcal H_t$-martingale. Indeed, $\mathbb E(M_{t+T}|\mathcal H_t) = \mathbb E(M_{t+T}|\mathcal F_{t+T}) = T X_{t+T}$ rather than $M_t$.

Comment: In discrete time the  answer is yes, isn't it, and the H fields are not different from the F fields ?

Comment: I was thinking of a discretization argument too @mike. But contnuity issues are tricky..

Comment: Wait a minute: $M_t$ has (locally) finite variation, so if it is a martingale, it is constant, right? But then $0=\frac d{dt}M_t =X_{t+T}-X_t$, and so $X_t$ is periodic with period $T$.

Comment: Oh wow, you are right of course. Damn.

Answer (score 3):

Let $X(t)$ be any deterministic $T$ periodic function, then

$$M(t)=\int_0^T X(s) ds=\operatorname{Const},$$

but $X(t)$ is not a martingale.

Comment: Oh wow I did not consider this..

Comment: Wait, actually because of the condition on the starting values of $X$, would not any such $T$-periodic function be constant?